# Decission between several position switches and one continuos position signal for controling rotating conveyor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, measurements, positions-measurement

We plan a conveyor that will dump something into containers. A level gauge on the tip of the container will measure the heap below. The conveyor is placed on a turntable and will e rotated horizontally a piece when the heap below is at a certain height, to make use of more of the container.

The system will look something like this but only drop of to one side:
[image]
*Image source: [DB Technologies BV](http://www.dbtechnologiesbv.nl/products/turntable-conveyor)*

I need to decide between either a continuos signal for the position of the turntable, or discrete signals at every point the conveyor will be. we are talking about 6-7 position signals in that case (3 per container plus maybe one so the conveyor is out of the way when both containers are moved). From the mechanical or process standpoint, I don't see a need for a continuos signal, 3 positions per container are fine enough.

I assume that this amount of signalers is even easier to implement than a continous sensor. Is this assumption correct?

Is there an argument from the control and measurement system side of things for a continous signal?

Comment: I would ask questions about your control objectives and the capabilities of you control actuators. What happens when the position is between your position switches? Can you be certain where the conveyor is, other than past position and direction of control? What kind of disturbances will there be?

Comment: The conveyor will only be between switches when moving from one drop off point to the next, or from one container to the other. I need to know for certain that it's above a container (on or between switch 1, 2, 3), else the conveyor has to be turned off. What do you mean by disturbance?

Comment: By disturbance, I mean anything "else" that could move the turntable. Guesses might be wind, rainstorm, mistake by a field operator, misplaced container, etc.